# URL Scanner breaks of line

Tags: java, url, stream

I have a website of which I want to read a number of.

I am using a scanner, but it always breaks off the line before reading he full line.

Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://whereisthemonkey.weebly.com/better-mob-ai.html");
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        //scanner.useDelimiter("\\n");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith("<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"I nformation")){
                line = line.replace(" ", "").replace("┬", "").replace("á", "");
                System.out.println(line);
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("Status:") + 7, line.indexOf("Status:") + 12);

                int latestVersion = Integer.valueOf(line);
                if(latestVersion == 0){
                    scanner.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    System.err.println("/=============================================================================\\");
                    System.err.println("|[Better MobAI] The developing team of Better MobAI encountered a major error:|");
                    System.err.println("|[Better MobAI] The plugin will be therefore disabled!                        |");  
                    System.err.println("\\============================================================================/");
                    return false;
                }
                if(latestVersion == 1){
                    scanner.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, because this is the output I get:

```
<metaproperty="og:description"content="InformationááááááááááááááááCurrentversion:1.9áááááááááááááááááááááááááááááááááááááááá..."/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the full line look like?

Comment: @MinhKieu I do not know, I am using weebly as a host and have no control over the website

Comment: Surely you can hit the website with the browser and view the html-source?

Comment: No, that is not possible on weebly, I already tried

Comment: Then how do you know that it didn't read the full line but break off halfway?

Comment: What is the number you need? Is the Current Version or Status or  what!!?

Comment: Index off returns -1, so how can I read the full line?

Comment: I need the number after "Status:" But the scanner breaks off the whole line with ... as you can see

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I get all HTML contents from your site like that:

[image]

Yesterday, I found only one of "Status" word. So, your condition in `if-statement` not correct, because the word not exist in line `startsWith` your condition.

Today, (Site Updated) I found two "Status" words. So, your condition in `if-statement` is correct which line contains this word. You may be change `endIndex` to `line.indexOf("Status:") + 8`. Another "Status" word will ignore because your condition `latestVersion == __` is `true` then `return` and break the loop.

**But wait..** this way uncomfortable for me, because the site will refresh every time. So, your conditions impossible to work fine.

So, I **recommended** for you to use `string.contains("Status");` for each line it reads. Like that:

```
public static boolean latestVersion() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://whereisthemonkey.weebly.com/better-mob-ai.html");
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    int numLine = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        numLine++;
        String status = "-1"; // equal any number like -1 which Status will never equal it
        if (line.contains("Status")) {
            int indexOfStatus = line.indexOf("Status");
            status = line.substring(indexOfStatus + 7, indexOfStatus + 9);
            System.out.println("line " + numLine + ": contains Status word | Status = " + status);
        }

        // use trim to avoid any spaces
        int latestVersion = Integer.parseInt(status.trim());
        if (latestVersion == 0) {
            scanner.close();
            inputStream.close();
            System.err.println("/=============================================================================\\");
            System.err.println("|[Better MobAI] The developing team of Better MobAI encountered a major error:|");
            System.err.println("|[Better MobAI] The plugin will be therefore disabled! |");
            System.err.println("\\============================================================================/");
            return false;
        }
        if (latestVersion == 1) {
            System.out.println("latestVersion: " + latestVersion);
            scanner.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    inputStream.close();
    return false;
}
```

---

**Just Tip**: Any connections to internet network use `Thread` to ensure your data is downloaded as all and it may take a long time.